# Apple script freezing won't start next task

Tags: applescript

I'm absolute nube with Apple script please help after first task apple script freezing and won't start next:

```
tell application "Cinebench" to activate
delay 5

tell application "System Events"
    key code 36 
    delay 5
    key code 36
    delay 3
    key code 4 using command down
    delay 60
end tell

tell application "DriveDx" to activate
delay 5
tell application "System Events"
    key code 36
end tell
```

DriveDx won't start and I can't stop script ( freezing)
Thanks

Comment: The script has over 1 minute of delays before trying to activate the DriveDx app, is that what you are calling "freezing"?

Comment: nop after 1 minute DriveDX failing to start I'm trying to stop script, but can't... will be freezing for 5 minutes then Apple event error comes up

Comment: DriveDx got an error:AppleEvent timed out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I know what's happened. DriveDx needs click.. Can't just press enter. Thanks anyway!